# Syslog4j - remove prefix from the message

Tags: java, syslog

Sample code:

```
final SyslogIF syslog = Syslog.getInstance(props.getProperty("protocol"));
final SyslogConfigIF config = syslog.getConfig();
config.setHost(props.getProperty("host"));
config.setPort(Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port")));
syslog.error(“Some message to log”);
```

Above code sends the message but prefixes date/time to the message. Wanted to remove that. How do I do that?

I am using syslog4j v 0.9.30.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is not the client that is attaching date/time to the message, but rather the syslog server which appends that info before dumping it to the file.